# PostgreSQL maximum connections based on api call or single app to db connection?

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm, database-concurrency

I'm using ElephantSQL's tiny turtle plan (5 concurrent connections). By "concurrent connections" does this mean when the application opens the connection (I'm using Gorm so `gorm.Open()`) on app startup, or does it mean on a per-query-basis?

I've sort-of narrowed it down, when making multiple async API calls I sometimes get the error `(pq: too many connections for role "x")`, so this leads me to think that the culprit is too many async API calls at once. However, I've also read that it is on an app-connection basis, such as using `gorm.Open()` to open the connection.

Just wanted some clarification in case I'm mismanaging my connections. Should also say that I've only used `gorm.Open()` once during app startup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A connection is a TCP connection between your application and the PostgreSQL database (ElephantSQL). FAQ: https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/faq.html#What_is_a_connection  It is concurrent (active) connections you have, which is specified on the pricing page. You can view (and terminate) connections on the Stats page.

Comment: Any ideas on why I would receive the "too many connections" error then? I'm only opening the connection once on app-startup.

Comment: What kind of connections do you see in the stats page? Is it connections from the same application? Are you starting the app many times?

Comment: It is connections from the same IP, must be the same application. I'm not starting the app many times. Beside the connection shows a "Query" column, which leads me to think connections are based on queries.